# Configure Ubuntu as Yum client

Tags: client, yum

Like in Red Hat, we make Yum client by getting into /etc/yum.repos.d/ and make a repo file For eg:-client.repo
The file mainly includes baseurl=ftp://[192.16.0.1]/pub/Packages

Is there any such path in ubuntu. So that we can store the packages in Red hat and install directly using networking.

I know how to download packages, If both the machines are running Red Hat. But, I don't know how to make ubuntu as yum client and download packages from Red Hat using FTP

Comment: You mean you want to configure a Yum *server* to serve packages to Red Hat? Or you want to install Red Hat packages onto Ubuntu?

Comment: I want to configure Red hat as yum server and serve packages to Ubuntu for installaton

Comment: Same question as above. Are the installation packages for ubuntu of the type _.deb_ or is it of the type _.rpm_?

Comment: Packages are in .rpm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot install `.rpm` based packages which were built for Red Hat, onto Ubuntu. Packages for Ubuntu are in `.deb` format, and installed using the `apt` package tools (or one of the many GUI tools built on top of it). If you wish to host a repository of packages to install on Ubuntu, they will need to be built properly using the correct tools to create the `.deb` packages, and will need to be hosted in an `apt` repository, using the appropriate tools to configure and update it. Alternatively, you can use the PPA system hosted on https://launchpad.net/ to build and host some packages for installation on Ubuntu.